# Создание поля счетчика формата xxxx в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Нужно для поля **code** задать автоматический счетчик который будет начинаться с 0001 и при последующих записях в таблицу код будет увеличиваться на 1, то есть 0002, 0003, и тд
Вот код, пытался сделать по документации, но не разобрался

```
SQL.execute("""CREATE TABLE if not exists ticketmes(
code char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
message_id BIGINT,
channel_id BIGINT)""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том виде, что ты хочешь, Пострис не даст сделать. Все автоматические счётчики и последовательности у него числовые.

Сделай обычный числовой автоинкремент и форматируй на лету

```
select lpad(code::text, 5, '0') as code from ticketmes
```

Если Постгрис 12 и выше, то можно сделать автовычислямую колонку

```
CREATE TABLE ticketmes (
        id serial,
        code char(5) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( lpad(id::text,5,'0') ) STORED ,
        message_id BIGINT,
        channel_id BIGINT
);
insert into ticketmes default values;
insert into ticketmes default values;
select * from ticketmes;
-- 1 00001 null null
-- 2 00002 null null
```

Comment: Спасибо, второй вариант для меня подходит, так как я использую постгре 12.4